# Android MediaStore - SQLiteException: No Such Column: Title

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I am trying to get a list of songs to fill a recyclerview. I have every other tab sorted, but for all songs, It refuses to work. I am using `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE`.

This is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: title (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, artist, album FROM album_info ORDER BY title ASC
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:493)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:435)
at xyz.timmo.music.SongsFragment$GetAlbums.doInBackground(SongsFragment.java:88)
at xyz.timmo.music.SongsFragment$GetAlbums.doInBackground(SongsFragment.java:71)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My cursor method is as so:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{
            //MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM
            //MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    },
    null,
    null,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
);
if (cursor != null) {
    //count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        artArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID)));
        songsArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
        artistsArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST)));
        albumsArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     cursor.close();
}
```

So what is the right string to fetch? All other topics suggest to use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` but this seems to be missing. Is this something which was removed in the latest sdk?

Comment: What are you expecting `TITLE` to be? From my reading of [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.html), `ALBUM` is the name of the album.

Comment: I am looking for TITLE  but this causes an SQLiteException.

Comment: Then get rid of `TITLE`. You are loading a list of albums. The name of the album would appear to be in the `ALBUM` column.

Comment: Well I need TITLE to get the title of the song. I am actually loading the TITLE, ALBUM, ARTIST, and _ID for the album art later on

Comment: You are not querying for songs. You are querying for albums. If you want to query for songs, use a different `Uri`.

Comment: Can you explain what I should be fetching?

Comment: Oh I just figured it out. I was fetching MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI when iI should be fetching MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. Thanks for the pointer @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was fetching `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` in the cursor when I should be fetching `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

Here is the working code for future reference:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                //MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
                //MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
        },
        null,
        null,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
);
if (cursor != null) {
    //count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        artArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID)));
        songsArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
        artistsArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST)));
        albumsArrayList.add(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
```